# Google App Engine Backend Instance Hours are double expected

Tags: java, google-app-engine, billing

I have written a Java application that I am running on GAE as a webapp.
Here is an extract from my appengine-web.xml:

```
<version>2</version>
<threadsafe>true</threadsafe>
<manual-scaling>
    <instances>1</instances>
</manual-scaling>
```

My app is written to listen for changes to a Firebase database, so I am expecting it to run continuously.  My problem is that I am being billed for 48 hours of 'Backend Instance Hours' per day instead of the expected 24 hours per day.

I have checked that I only have one instance running. I have not stopped or started it (I know that that adds another 15 minutes).  Looking at my usage history, it clearly says that I have used 48 hours of Backend Instance Hours in a day. I have no idea where to look now.  Can anyone help please?

Comment: What instance class do you use?

Answer (score 5):

From the doc: https://cloud.google.com/appengine/pricing#standard_instance_pricing

“When you are billed for instance hours, you will not see any instance classes in your billing line items. Instead, you will see the appropriate multiple of instance hours. For example, if you use an F4 instance for one hour, you do not see "F4" listed, but you see billing for four instance hours at the F1 rate.”

I would recommend to focus on calculating the cost based on the instance class you are using and see if the bill is high or accurate. Accordingly, you may contact [billing support](https://cloud.google.com/support/billing/#contact_support) to clear any discrepancies.

Comment: Thank you - I had not specified an instance class, but I have read that the default for manual-scaling is B2.  This would explain why I have been charged the 48 hours.  I have now specified a class of B1, and hopefully, when I check tomorrow, this will be resolved.

Comment: Thanks for following up!

Comment: Looks like B2 = 2 x F1, and everything is in terms of F1 hours. The multipliers can be deduced from here: https://cloud.google.com/appengine/pricing#standard_instance_pricing

Answer (score 2):

Maybe do you have more than one version running.

You could check on  https://console.cloud.google.com/appengine/versions

By the way you could use [Firebase Cloud functions](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/) instead of the Google App Engine Manual Scalling to listen for changes on Firebase Database.